# SQL results into PHP array, not expected output

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get all the results from 1 column into an array. I tried the following below but all I get from the output is "Array".

```
$sql = "SELECT pickID FROM picks WHERE userID = 2 ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$i = 0;
$pickArray = array();

foreach($result as $row) {
    $pickArray[$i] = $row['pickID'];
    $i++;
}

echo $pickArray;
```

Comment: try `print_r($pickArray)` instead of `echo`.

Comment: note- your current code will only return 1 value as `mysql_fetch_array()` ->`Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead`. If more than 1 value is desired, remove `$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);` and change `foreach($result as $row) {` to `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){`

Comment: Thanks Sean for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `print_r` not `echo`. See why you need to use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for viewing values of an array. [Echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) on the other hand is being used to display value of a variable not array.

> `print_r($pickArray);`

Also a **note** from Sean,

remove `$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);` and change `foreach($result as $row) {` to `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){`

Comment: Your answer and sean's answer did the job

Comment: See my Edit using Sean's suggestion